Cytoscape & fCoSE: Shouldn't sibling nodes respect bounds-expansion?
Here is a jsbin demonstrating the issue:
https://jsbin.com/qeqokuy/2/edit?html,output
You might need to run it a couple times to see the issue clearly.
What I would expect is that when laying out compound nodes with bounds-expansion at the top, as you see in the demo, that not only would parent compound nodes avoid the expanded area, but also sibling nodes. In the demo, the areas marked in red should be vacant.
I need this because I want to draw a variable-height header atop each of my compound nodes.
Do I misunderstand the feature, or is it a bug?


As far as I can tell, the bounds-expansion property is only used for node images going over the normal bounds of a node, not preventing other nodes to enter that area.

A compound parent node does not have independent dimensions (position and size), as those values are automatically inferred by the positions and dimensions of the descendant nodes.

To solve your problem, you probably have to include every parentless node and current parent node inside another parent. This way, the nodes are all contained in the bounding box of that parent.
